# An alternative to "endearing," used to mean "make more expensive"

Tags: single-word-requests

I love the concept of the word 'endearing' meaning 'to make more dear/expensive', but it is apparently obsolete. Is there any word or short phrase that can replace it?

Sample sentence: "Transport is the 'endearing' factor of the vacation"

Comment: "... the factor that jacks up the price ..."

Comment: "Transportation is the price hiking factor of the vacation"

Comment: "Vacation expenses are highly sensitive to transport costs".

Answer (score 1):

*Make more expensive* was the original, now obsolete,  meaning of  ***[to endear](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/endear)*** :

> - to make dear, esteemed, or beloved: He endeared himself to us with his gentle ways.
> - ( Obsolete) - to make costly.

(Random House Kernerman Webster's College)

From  [vocabulary.com](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/endear)

> - In the 1500s, endear meant "increase the value of," though it quickly came to mean "make dear," or perhaps to increase the emotional value, especially of another person.

[Endear](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=endear&allowed_in_frame=0): (Etymonline)

> - 1580s, "to enhance the value of," also "win the affection of," from en- (1) "make, put in" + dear (adj.). Meaning "to make dear," ***the main modern is from 1640s.***

- Regarding your sentence, You can express the concept saying that : *transportation is the  more expensive part of the vacation,* or *transportation is what makes the vacation expensive*.

Answer (score 1):

Sample sentence: "Transport is the 'endearing' factor of the vacation"

How aobut using "cost-fuelling" or "cost-raising" factor? instead of endearing factor?

I don't think people will have difficulty in understanding what they mean.

Answer (score 1):

You could also turn your sentence the other way around and say:

*transportation is the most **empoverishing** factor of vacationing*

Answer (score 0):

I would just say expensive, because that is exactly what it is.